# Custom Action Bar Shift a bit

Tags: android, xml

I have a custom Action bar on my application, but the position is not fit on the screen. The action bar shifts a bit and it's really annoying since I cannot solve this bug. Is there something with my **styles.xml**?

Any hints and solution will be really appreciated.

[image: screenshot]

styles.xml

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<!--
    Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
    by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.




-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.




    -->
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
</style>

<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>

<style name="PhotosGridView">
    <item name="android:horizontalSpacing">1dp</item>
    <item name="android:numColumns">auto_fit</item>
    <item name="android:stretchMode">columnWidth</item>
    <item name="android:verticalSpacing">1dp</item>
</style>

<style name="PhotoGridLayout">
    <item name="android:drawSelectorOnTop">true</item>
    <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/photogrid_list_selector</item>
</style>

<style name="ThemeForHome" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/menu_icon</item>
</style>

<style name="GeneralLabelFont">
    <item name="android:textSize">15sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
</style>

<style name="LoginLabelFont" parent="GeneralLabelFont">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/light_blue</item>
</style>

<style name="SubscriptionLabelFont" parent="GeneralLabelFont">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="LoginDialogListItemPaddings">
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">5dp</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Translucent</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/transparent_black</item>
    <item name="android:colorForeground">#fff</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Are you using toolbar? It seems to be left margin added to layout in which you have added toolbar. @satryaway

Comment: post actoinbar code here.

Comment: public void initActionBar(View actionBar) {
  getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(actionBar, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
  getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME);
  getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
  getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
  getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
  getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

 }

Answer (score 0):

I've faced a simliar issue in my app. This is how I set my custom ActionBar:

```
final ViewGroup actionBarLayout = (ViewGroup) getLayoutInflater().inflate(
        R.layout.your_custom_action_bar_layout,
        null);
final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
```

An here are the parameters I set:

```
actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false); // This line removes the space
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
actionBar.setCustomView(actionBarLayout);
```